# Is it not repetition to say "semantic meaning"?

Tags: grammar, repetition

I was going through an article on wikipedia and somewhere it said, "the semantic meaning of [noun here] is twofold ......"
When I look up the word semantic, to me, it is like a defining word that implicitly implies "meaning". Is this not a grammatical mistake?

Comment: Superfluous redundancy is not usually a ***grammatical*** mistake. It may be a stylistic one.

Comment: [Difference between *semantic meaning* and *pragmatic meaning*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100746/semantic-or-pragmatic-ambiguity)

Comment: It's not a redundancy because as Andrew shows with his link, there is more than one kind of meaning.  There's also literal and figurative meaning.

Comment: Exactly. And there's phonosemantic "meaning", as [the KL- words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) show. And there's lots of other kinds of "meaning", which essentially refers to any kind of interpersonal information exchange, by any (*ahem*) means at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "close proximity" a tautology?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38678/is-close-proximity-a-tautology)

Comment: I think you are confused about what a “grammatical” mistake would be.

Comment: I thought repetition was considered a grammatical mistake. Clearly it's not. Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: Grammar usually means sytax, the ordering of words and word elements. Semantics or meaning is separate. 'Colorless green ideas slep furiously' is the classic example of a perfectly well-formed -grammatical- sentence, but has lots of semantic...difficulties.

Comment: Is sleping sleeping unesily?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it is redundant. The semantic meaning is only one type of meaning. For example, if somebody is being sarcastic then the actual meaning can be the opposite of the semantic meaning. Of course, a dictionary can usually only deal in semantic meaning, so perhaps it was unnecessary in that particular context, but it remains a useful distinction.

Answer (score -3):

There's no grammatical problem, but I think it is redundant, as you can just say "the semantics of...".

The argument above, that points out that there is more than one kind of meaning, doesn't follow. It's circular logic. It's not relevant whether there are other types of meanings. As you pointed out in the question, the word *semantics* means 'meaning', so the word *meaning* is redundant, and does not need defining. It doesn't need to be there at all.

Comment: The word "semantics" is a lot more than just a synonym for "meaning".

Comment: And?? Consider the context. There's no need to say "the semantic meaning of..." when you could say "the semantics of" so the comments above, despite the back slapping, are missing the basics. (cue downvotes...)

Comment: "*The speaker had implicated, pragmatically, that the film was terrible. The semantic meaning of his words, however, remained positive*". Here is an example where the stress of meaning is helpful.

Comment: Also, remember the OP asked if "semantic meaning" is a mistake. Just because there are other ways of saying it, ways that might sound to some, subjectively, to be more stylistically appropriate, doesn't make "semantic meaning" a mistake. It would be a poor language that only allowed one way of saying something.

Comment: I never said it was a mistake. I said it was redundant.

Comment: As is often the case, OP's second question is not an exact paraphrase of that in the post title, muddying the waters. Addressing just the redundancy issue, if 'semantic meaning' is used in a different sense from 'pragmatic meaning' (as it obviously is by at least some respected authorities), it has acquired compound-noun status and a sense not necessarily equivalent to the linear sum of its parts. _Gorilla gorilla_ seems acceptable to taxonomists.